# How to clean the content of UIWebView without loading an empty page?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I need to clean the content of UIWebView(in order to reuse it), but I have some authentication handling code in its delegate methods, so I do not want to load an empty page like about:blank to clean it, as it will trigger my authentication handling code. So is there a way for doing this?
(also, by reusing it, I need to put a spinner on top of the web view, and when it loads another page, I don't want the user see the previous loaded page content, so that's why I need to clean it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can just use this line of code :

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

[Here](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/webview-clean-content) you will find whole demo

Comment: Yes I know this, but what I asked is a way without loading "about:blank" if you read my question. Thanks all the same!

Comment: you can't do what you want you have to do like this there isn't any other way to do this.

Answer (score 25):

this did the trick for me:

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.open();document.close()"];
```

Comment: I found that this solution blocks my main thread for long 4 seconds while cleaning a big webview.

Comment: It seems any js will block the main thread so keep in mind. There is no chance to launch it on background thread though

Comment: I had +1'ed this answer a few years ago, but on iOS 9 WebView started to crash sometimes if I do this too often (every time when a user presses "Back" button); also tried `performSelectorOnMainThread:`, no luck. The version from @Nilesh (load `about:blank`) does the trick without crashes.

Answer (score 8):

Try this out. This worked for me

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is that the spinner disappears when you load a blank page, you can use this code in webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
– (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)currentWebView {
    if (![currentWebView.request.URL.description isEqualToString: @"about:blank"]) {
        self.mySpinner.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

...then the spinner will go on until your webview is actually done loading.