# Opening a PDF url in UIWebView and copying from it, crashes the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I am opening many urls from my application and they are working fine. All these urls I am opening in `UIWebView` in a custom `ViewController`.

But recently I found an issue that when I am passing a url which contains a **PDF**, it opens fine , but when I copy something from that PDF by long pressing on the PDF from `UIWebView`, and then when I try to go back from that `ViewController`, the app crashes giving me error like:

**[UIPDFPageView nextResponder]: message sent to deallocated instance**

Without copying any thing I can normally go back and continue with my app. I tried a lot but could not figure out the problem.

If any one can help, It will be honor.
Thanks in advance... !!!

Comment: I hope you have made UIWebview object a property with strong attribute in the ViewController.

Comment: Yes it is a strong property...

Comment: what is UIPDFPageView? That's not an iOS framework class I suppose ...

Comment: That's not a direct class available for using but I guess it is used internally while manipulating PDFs in UIWebView...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might be calling the below line when going back from your `UIWebView`'s `ViewController` :

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

May be to clear out your `WebView` before leaving. There are better and easy ways to so this like given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909329/how-to-clean-the-content-of-uiwebview-without-loading-an-empty-page):

Hope this helps...
All the best!!!